# Accessing login page appends ReturnUrl on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, forms-authentication

I have a webforms application configured to use forms authentication. It works on my development machine but since I configured it on IIS, I get a ReturnUrl on my login page with the application name, Upon logging in I get back to the same login page logged in but without the returnUrl. Logging in again redirects me to the correct page finally

> How can I stop this ReturnUrl appearing on my login page?

```
http://localhost/myApp/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2MyApp%2f
```

I have checked directory permissions & allowed all users on login page with authorization tag in my web.config but it does not work. Some of my web.config

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="MyAuthCookie" timeout="30" loginUrl="login.aspx"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
.
.
.
  <location path="login.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `defaultUrl` tag and give the name of page where you want to redirect after login.
Suppose you want login and redirect to "xyz.aspx" page then you have to add below code in web.config file
Note: don't give `loginUrl` tag.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="MyAuthCookie" timeout="30" defaultUrl="xyz.aspx"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
```